# Learning iPhone SDK (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hey programmers!
I really want to learn how to program really cool games and iphone apps but unfortunately, I don't know Objective-C. My school only offers Java courses (which I'm not fond of) and I really want to take a class or get a tutor. ANYTHING SO I CAN LEARN THIS LANGUAGE. I've got great app ideas but can't lay 'em out on paper. I currently am attending school and I cant really take any classes now, but I'm looking forward to some (I still haven't found any) during the summer, over in Chicago. I'm located in Chicago and am able to travel anywhere by train. I really want to learn the language of programming so respond with some help or a course/class. Thanks very much guys!

Comment: What exactly is it about java that you don't like? It is probably the easier of the 2 languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development and Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c)

Comment: There are many resources at the above-linked question for getting started, so this question most likely will be closed.  However, if you're in the Chicago area, you should attend the local CocoaHeads chapter, or take part in the NSCoder nights there: http://groups.google.com/group/cawug?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Some helpful links:

- [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163)
- [Getting Started with iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/index.html)
- [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
- [iTunes U: Stanford — Developing Apps for iOS by Paul Hegarty](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774)
- [iTunes U: Stanford — iPhone Application Development by Alan Cannistraro and Josh Shaffer](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225)

Comment: I commend your post. Nice collection of course links.

Answer (score 2):

try online courses. I did the Stanford videos from itunesU

Essentially you

- log into itunes
- select itunesu..
- search for Stanford

the lectures were video taped and uploaded to itunes.

Some important things to remember are.
every objective c object is retained when you want to keep it, released when you want to get rid of it and autoreleased when you are going to pass it on to another part of code, but are done using it yourself.

you can send anything to nil, and everything in objective c is a message. even properties.

on another note, objective C is essentially C. but with the next step framework built on top. and apple built on that to create their own framework. just get the fundamentals down and you will be good. The rest is just learning how to find the messages you want.

Oh, another important fact. These lessons in iTunesU, are Free..... and are Fairly In depth, yet still easy to understand.

Comment: nice hints for object-lifecicle and messaging.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate the criticism.

Answer (score 1):

Learning a language doesn't require a class (computer science courses are valuable for the general skills and knowledge they impart, not so much the language they teach). Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming), install the developer tools and SDK and get crackin'. I did it for the Mac when I was 17. My first app that I made all by myself was an international clock so I could tell whether it was an obscene hour to ping my friends in Europe and Asia. It was simple, but a good learning experience.