# Xcode 4 automatically created files?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I am new to Xcode and iOS development. when I create a new project, automatically Xcode create many files ended with:
`AppDelegate.h` 
`AppDelegate.m` 
`mainwindow.xlib` 
`ViewController.h` 
`ViewController.m` 
`ViewController.xlib`

What are these files?

Comment: How much of the documentation have you read?

Comment: My book ("Programming iOS 4", from O'Reilly) explains the behavior and contents of all of Apple's application templates.

Comment: @Deepak. I am a beginner, this means I do not know if the documentation is good or bad or cover this topic or not. If you think it is good you can help me in a nice way.

Comment: @usef_ksa you can trust Apple's documentation. Read the Objective-C programming guide, iOS Application programming guide, iOS Technology Overview, Cocoa Fundamentals and iOS HIG. Lot of stuff but all of it is good content.

Comment: some useful links for beginners: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656626/learning-iphone-sdk-objective-c/5656783#5656783

Comment: dears, deepak, matt &vikingosegundo, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reference [The Core Application Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW16) section of the [Core Application Design](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html).

> The role of objects in an iOS
>   application

**UIApplication object** (AppDelegate Related)

> The UIApplication object manages the
>   application event loop and coordinates
>   other high-level behaviors for your
>   application. You use this object as
>   is, mostly to configure various
>   aspects of your application’s
>   appearance. Your custom
>   application-level code resides in your
>   application delegate object, which
>   works in tandem with this object.
>   Application delegate object The
>   application delegate is a custom
>   object that you provide at application
>   launch time, usually by embedding it
>   in your application’s main nib file.
>   The primary job of this object is to
>   initialize the application and present
>   its window onscreen. The UIApplication
>   object also notifies this object when
>   specific application-level events
>   occur, such as when the application
>   needs to be interrupted (because of an
>   incoming message) or moved to the
>   background (because the user tapped
>   the Home button). For more information
>   about this object, see [“The
>   Application Delegate.”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW32)

**Data model objects** (These will be available when you include CoreData in your project)

> Data model objects store your
>   application’s content and are
>   therefore specific to your
>   application. For example, a banking
>   application might store a database
>   containing financial transactions,
>   whereas a painting application might
>   store an image object or even the
>   sequence of drawing commands that led
>   to the creation of that image. (In the
>   latter case, an image object is still
>   a data object because it is just a
>   container for the image data. The
>   actual rendering of that image still
>   takes place elsewhere in your
>   application.)

**View controller objects** (ViewController.h and ViewController.m are your source files and ViewController.xib is your interface builder file)

> View controller objects manage the
>   presentation of your application’s
>   content. Typically, this involves
>   creating the views to present that
>   content and managing the interactions
>   between the views and your
>   application’s data model objects. The
>   UIViewController class is the base
>   class for all view controller objects.
>   It provides default functionality for
>   animating the appearance of views,
>   handling device rotations, and many
>   other standard system behaviors. UIKit
>   and other frameworks also define other
>   view controller classes for managing
>   standard system interfaces, such as
>   navigation interfaces or the image
>   picker. For detailed information about
>   how to use view controllers, see View
>   Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

**UIWindow object** (mainwindow.xib is the interface builder file that links your window and other objects together with your AppDelegate)

> A UIWindow object coordinates the
>   presentation of one or more views on
>   the device screen or on an external
>   display. Most applications have only
>   one window, the content of which is
>   provided by one or more views. An
>   application changes the content of
>   that window by changing the current
>   set of views (usually with the help of
>   a view controller object). In addition
>   to hosting views, windows are also
>   responsible for delivering events to
>   those views and to their managing view
>   controllers.

**View, control, and layer objects** (These will belong to your view controllers)

> Views and controls provide the visual
>   representation of your application’s
>   content. A view is an object that
>   draws content in a designated
>   rectangular area and responds to
>   events within that area. Controls are
>   a specialized type of view responsible
>   for implementing familiar interface
>   objects such as buttons, text fields,
>   and toggle switches. The UIKit
>   framework provides standard views for
>   presenting many different types of
>   content. You can also define your own
>   custom views by subclassing UIView (or
>   its descendants) directly. In addition
>   to incorporating views and controls,
>   applications can also incorporate Core
>   Animation layers into their view and
>   control hierarchies. Layer objects are
>   actually data objects that represent
>   visual content. Views use layer
>   objects intensively behind the scenes
>   to render their content. You can also
>   add custom layer objects to your
>   interface to implement complex
>   animations and other types of
>   sophisticated visual effects.