# 'UITabBarController' may not respond to '-method'

Tags: objective-c, ios

My setup: MainWindow with a Tab Bar Controller (including a Tab Bar) and two `UIViewController`s, both assigned to the same interface which extends `UIViewController`. This custom interface implements a `IBOutlet` Webview and a void that loads a URL. On `didSelectViewController` on the main .m I try to call `LoadURL`.

.m of the view controller

```
@implementation MyTabBarController
@synthesize webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
return [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
}

- (void) LoadURL: (NSString*)s {
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

.h of the view controller

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTabBarController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

- (void) LoadURL: (NSString*)s;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

.m of the main window

```
- (void) tabBarController: (UITabBarController *) myController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController {
[myController LoadURL:@"http://google.com"]; // WARNING 
}
```

I put breakpoints on each of the voids and they get called. But my webView doesn't show any content.

Other than that I got 2 warnings:

```
'UITabBarController' may not respond to '-LoadURL:'
Semantic Issue: Method '-LoadURL:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Comment: Are you defining the LoadURL method in the view controller header file? If so, how are you defining it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my post to include the .h file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have to cast it, if you are sure it isn't a UIViewController but a subclass of it

```
[(MyTabBarController*)myController LoadURL:@"http://google.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks and yes, I already thought of that. It is a subclass of UIViewController. But I get: 'MyTabBarController' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Could you please hint me how to import it?

Comment: at the beginning of your file `#import "MyTabBarController.h"` or whatever the file is called, your class resides in

Comment: Thanks. Now that I've imported it, MyTabBarController can be resolved. But I still get a warning: 'MyTabBarController may not respond to '-LoadURL:'

Comment: did you declare -LoadURL: in MyTabBarController.h? Can u show us the file?

Comment: u have an implementation for `-LoadData:`. but did u declare it in the `@interface`?

Comment: I've got - (void) LoadURL: (NSString*)s; after @interface in my .h file of the custom UIViewController. Is this correct?

Comment: u have the implementation `@implementation MyTabBarController` but the interface `@interface MyController : UIViewController` this doesnt belong together. The name of a class most match. for it interface and implementation.

Comment: I am sorry. This is a typo because you named it like that as an example and I tried to follow that thought. The names of implementation and interface match in my project files.

Comment: Error: NSInvalidArgumentException, UITabBarController LoadURL: unrecognized selector sent...

Comment: ok, can you upload the project folder somewhere? I'd like to see it in action

Comment: I made it work. I used viewController (instead of myController) as in Noah's comment and your cast suggestion, ran a clean and reassigned File's owner and Outlet stuff. I'm not exactly sure what fixed it. Anyway thank you very much for your effort. I will upvote you as soon as I have 15 pts.

Comment: Good you made it work. I put some links together for iOS development. They might be useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656626/learning-iphone-sdk-objective-c/5656783#5656783

Answer (score 0):

Your `-LoadURL:` method is not defined on `UITabBarController`.  Perhaps you mean to do

```
[self LoadURL:@"http://google.com"];
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

@Dave I don't get it, sorry: self did not work for me. Maybe because -LoadURL is not in the same file but in the .m of my custom view controller?

@Noah Doesn't work, still get the warning.