# Simple line using UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I want to draw simple line above all the subviews using UIPinchGestureRecognizer any suggestion to do that

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw Line with gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436990/draw-line-with-gesture)

Answer (score 1):

This should work: Assign the gesturerecognizer to the `window` and add and move a view you added to window as-well.

Comment: how to implement that ., I have viewcontroller , that contain many subviews I want to draw line above all using gesture

Comment: each view has a window property, that is not nil, if the view was added to the view hierarchy properly. the window is the top view of your app. anything you add by `[aView.window addSubview:anotherView]` will be above all other views.

Comment: I do self.vew addsubview not like that

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying.

Comment: I have a window applications classes that inheret from UIViewController , I uses [self addsubview view2] ; I never used [aView.window addSubview:anotherView]

Comment: of course you are not, otherwise you wouldn't had to asked this question!

Comment: Try it, and you'll see that I am right, that this is the way to lay a view over any other!

Comment: you mean do [self.window addsubview:view2 ] ;

Comment: if you are inside the View instead of the viewController: yes.

Comment: I have class has nib file and this is part of it @interface Viewer : UIViewController < UIActionSheetDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>{ , I cannot understand forgive me I am newbie

Comment: sorry, I gave you a precise answer, but you are lacking on understanding objective-c, the model view contoller pattern and the view hierarchy. If I tried to help you further, it would mean I have to teach you from the beginning. I dont have time for that. But I collected some resources. You should work yourself trough at least some of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656626/learning-iphone-sdk-objective-c/5656783#5656783

Comment: am just asking what's the difference between say self.window or aview. what do u mena by aview

Comment: I added it as subview to self.view , beacause adding it to self.view.window cover the navigationbar any suggestion why that happened ,