# Thread 1: Programm received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to build an easy application with View swiching and UIWebView
it worked till i wrote the UIWebView

```
-(IBAction)pushButton { 

    TermineViewController *screen = [[TermineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; 
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES]; thread 1: program receved signal: "SIGaBRT"
    [screen release]; 
}

-(IBAction)pushButton2 {

    SpeiseplanViewController *screen = [[SpeiseplanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];




//
//  TermineViewController.m
//  LhAppv3
//
//  Created by joan on 03.07.11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TermineViewController.h"


@implementation TermineViewController

-(IBAction)pushBack {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/* 
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 { 
 [super viewDidLoad]; 
 } 
 */ 

-(void)viewDidLoad { 

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.landheim-schondorf.de/news/"]]]; 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkNotLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

} 

-(void)checkLoad { 

    if(webView.loading) { 
        [active startAnimating]; 

    } 

} 

-(void)ckeckNotLoad { 

    if(!(webView.loading)) { 
        [active stopAnimating]; 

    } 

} - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end


//
//  TermineViewController.h
//  LhAppv3
//
//  Created by joan on 03.07.11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TermineViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *active;
}

-(IBAction)pushBack;

@end
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the crash or the code of _TermineViewController_. That's probably where the cause of the error is.

Comment: the code of the .h or .m ????

Comment: 'the code of the .h or .m ????' -> both

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:aRect]; //<--------
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.landheim-schondorf.de/news/"]]]; 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkNotLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

}
```

Additionally you need to release webView in dealloc. And you should get confortable with properties.

Try to catch the bug with the help of zombies: [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

Comment: ich just worked with this two tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P7sadlxBuQ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P7sadlxBuQ

Comment: wirklich gute docs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656626/learning-iphone-sdk-objective-c/5656783#5656783 Besonders Stanford mit Hagerty (But we have to talk english :D)

Comment: Expected * before * Expected expression before 'Rect'

Comment: du, ich weiss nicht, welchen Fehler du jetzt hast, beim initialisieren der webView musst du ein frame von typ NSRect übergeben. ich habe aber nicht genug Kenntnis, wie dein Projekt sonst aussieht. Wenn ich ehrlich bin denke ich, dass dir eine ganze Menge Verständnis für Cocoa/Objective-C fehlt und du solltest dir gerade Hegarty ganz genau anschauen.

Comment: dass mir Kenntnis fehlt ist mir klar dass ist auch mein erstes Projekt

Comment: ok ich habe es noch einmal neu gemacht jetzt wird die Meldung aber in der main.m angezeigt :-(