# UIAlertView with Button linking alternate ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I needed a button that causes a UIAlertView with actions to pop up.

Once the Alert pops up it needs to have 1 button to cancel and stay on the same page and 1 button that links you to another ViewController.

This is what I pieced together from some forums but I have no idea what I'm doing and it gives me about 9 error messages. Please Help!

```
-(IBAction)Alert:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *Alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                              message:@"Warning! By entering the Tutorial, all data will be lost. Are you sure you want to continue?" 
                                             delegate:self 
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Return to Data Collection" 
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
    [Alert Show];
    [Alert Release];
}
```

```
- (void)Alert:(UIAlertView *)Alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(Alert.tag==0) {

        if(buttonIndex == 1)//OK button pressed
        {
            Tutorial *Info = [[Tutorial alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:Info animated:YES];
        }
```

The first box of code works so that when I press a button on my home screen an alert with 2 buttons pops up.

However, I can't get the second button to link me to the next ViewController.

Answer (score 3):

1. Objective-C is case-sensitive.

   ```
   [Alert show];
   [Alert release];
   ```

   and

   ```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)Alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   ```

   <sub>(How do you think, it can work, if you rename the methods???)</sub>
2. remove `if(Alert.tag==0) {`
3. Why are you not passing a name for a nib-file here: `Tutorial *Info = [[Tutorial alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`
4. Please stick to coding conventions. objects are named in camelCase.

**Conclusion**
get you a good book or videos to learn from the beginning. [Some resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656626/learning-iphone-sdk-objective-c/5656783#5656783) to do so.

Comment: Passing nil for nibName is fine - it just loads a nib whose name matches the class name - Tutorial.xib in this case. Of course if the nib isn't called that then you'd have a problem.